# jQuery on textarea selectionchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I handle the `selectionchange` event of a `textarea`?

I tried:

```
$('#editor').on('selectionchange', function () {
   console.log(arguments);               
});
```

Not working. Am I wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: jst use 'change' instead of 'selectionchange'. Or explain your actual requirement

Comment: @Pedram Am writing an small markdown editor for my angular project. need to detect when user selects a text in textarea.

Comment: did you try on `mouseup` or even `click`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `selectionchange` event is fired when the current text selection on a `document` is changed. This event works only if target object is a `document`. This event for `HTML Input Element` and `HTML Text Area Element`, only supported in Firefox 52 and above. See the [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/selectionchange#Browser_compatibility).

So, Do you need to get the selected text in a `textarea`? You may be asking for `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` (does not exist in Internet Explorer, works with Firefox and Chrome). See the example below:

**Example:**

```js
$( document ).on( 'mouseup', 'body', function() {
  console.clear();

  if ( getSelectionText() ) console.log( getSelectionText() )
});

function getSelectionText() {
  if ( window.getSelection ) {
    try {
      var tarea = $( 'textarea' ).get(0);

      return ( tarea.selectionStart !=  tarea.selectionEnd ) ? 'The event triggered. You select "' + tarea.value.substring( tarea.selectionStart,  tarea.selectionEnd ) + '"' : '';
    } catch ( e ) {
        console.log( 'Cant get selection text' )
      }
    }

    // For IE
    if ( document.selection && document.selection.type != 'Control' )
      return document.selection.createRange().text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea>Salam textarea</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that by using focus HTML:

```
<form>
 <input id="target" type="text" value="Field 1">
 <input type="text" value="Field 2">
</form>
<div id="other">
 Trigger the handler
</div>
```

Javascript

```
  $( "#target" ).focus(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .focus() called." );
  });
```

By the example above you will find an idea on how you will be able to use focus to solve your problem